# Null-route/blacklist certain websites on IPtables router

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, domain, bind, blacklist

I've set up a home server to work as a router/NAT. This is done with IPtables forwarding rule.

Now I'd like to block certain websites, like facebook. I thought I could just add `127.0.0.1 facebook.com` to `/etc/hosts` on the server, but the client (my) computer could still access/ping the domain.

I'm also running bind, maybe it could be done with that? Thanks for you help.

Comment: And if anyone is curious, I'd like to block facebook to stop me from checking it all the time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming bind is the DNS server on the router, and that your computer is using said router for DNS resolution.  Edit:  If your computer is using your ISPs DNS servers directly, this won't work at all.  Skip to the iptables section.)

Bind isn't going to use the local server's /etc/hosts to find out what facebook is.  If you want to break facebook you'd need to tell bind that it's authoritative for the facebook.com domain, and set up a zonefile with 127.0.0.1 (for example) as the A record for facebook.com and www.facebook.com.

A simpler approach might be to add iptables rules for the IPs used by facebook.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s <computer IP> -d 69.63.189.11 -p tcp -j REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD -s <computer IP> -d 69.63.189.16 -p tcp -j REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD -s <computer IP> -d 69.63.181.12 -p tcp -j REJECT
```

That or self-control :-P.

Comment: I vote for self-control.